# How to check if bit variable is true or false in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple query and all I want to do is check if this variable is true or false, and for some reason it always returns false.

```
DECLARE @CappedIFCheck BIT
SET @CappedIFCheck = (SELECT distinct 1
                      FROM mytable
                      WHERE 1=1);

select @CappedIFCheck
     IF (@CappedIFCheck = 'True')
        BEGIN
           SELECT 'true';
        END
     ELSE
        BEGIN
           SELECT 'false';
        END
```

Comment: I had to edit it sorry

Comment: Works for me. Is `mytable` empty? You should just use `IF EXISTS` anyway though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A `bit` variable in SQL Server can have three values. `0`, `1` and `NULL`.

The strings `'true'` and `'false'` map to `1` and `0` respectively.

Your code does not take account of the third possible value. If `mytable` is empty then the variable will not be initialised and have the value `NULL`.

```
SELECT CASE @CappedIFCheck
         WHEN 'True' THEN 'true'
         WHEN 'False' THEN 'false'
         ELSE 'unknown'
       END
```

I'm not sure exactly what your code is trying to do but that is a very inefficient way of going about things. You should use `EXISTS` instead.

Comment: Good. FYI I defined a bit column as "not null" to avoid just that issues :)

Answer (score 38):

When comparing BIT values in Sql Server, use literal values 1 and 0 instead of 'True' and 'False'.

IF (@CappedIFCheck = 1) ...

Comment: [The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx)

Comment: That may be a good hint to avoid varchar casting, but for sure it doesn't change anything logic-wise

Answer (score 0):

Try the set clause like this:

```
SET @CappedIFCheck = ISNULL((select 1 where exists (select 1 from MyTable where 1=0)),0)
```